# Runtime complexity of the function

Tags: time-complexity

I have to find the time complexity of the following program:

```
function(int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)                   //O(n) times
        for(int j=i;j<i*i;j++)             //O(n^2) times
            if(j%i==0)
            {  //O(n) times
                for(int k=0;k<j;k++)       //O(n^2) times
                    printf("8");
            }
}
```

I analysed this function as follows:

```
i : O(n)  : 1        2        3          4             5
j :       : 1        2..3     3..8       4..15         5..24           (values taken by j)
    O(n^2): 1        2        6          12            20              (Number of times executed)
j%i==0    : 1        2        3,6        4,8,12        5,10,15,20      (Values for which the condition is true)
    O(n)  : 1        1        2          3             4
k         : 1        2        3,6        4,8,12        5,10,15,20      (Number of times printf is executed)
    Total : 1        2        9          24            50              (Total)
```

However I am unable to bring about any conclusions since I don't find any correlation between $i$ which is essentially O(n) and Total of k (last line). In fact I don't understand if we should be looking at the time complexity in terms of number of times `printf` is executed since that will neglect O(n^2) execution of j-for loop. The answer given was O(n^5) which I presume is wrong but then whats correct? To be more specific about my confusion I am not able to figure out how that `if(j%i==0)` condition have effect on the overall runtime complexity of the function.

Answer (score 0):

**The answer is definitely not O(n^5)**. It can be seen very easily. Suppose your second inner loop always runs `n^2` times and your innermost loop always runs `n` times, even then total time complexity would be **O(n^4)**.

Now let us see what is actual time complexity.

**1**.The outermost loop always runs O(n) times.

**2**.Now let us see how many times second inner loop runs for a single iteration of outer loop:

The loop will run

`0` time for `i = 0`

`0` time for `i = 1`

`2` times for `i = 2`
....

`i*i - i` times for `j = i`.

`i*i - i` is `O(i^2)`

**3**. Coming to the innermost loop, it runs only when `j` is divisble by `i` and `j` varies from `i to i*i-1`.

This means `j` goes through `i*1, i*2 , i*3` ..... till last multiple of `i` less than `i*i`. Which is clearly **O(i)**, Hence for a single iteration of second inner loop innermost loop runs **O(i)** times, this means total iterations of two inner loops is **O(i^3)**.

Summing up `O(i^3)` for i = 0 to n-1 will definitely give a term that is **O(n^4)**.

Therefore, the correct time complexity is **O(n^4)**.

Comment: ok so u too come up with same complexities of those individual loops as I stated in original question. However  I feel it is improper to sum those powers of n the way you did O(n)*O(n^2)*O(n)=O(n^4) in this case.  Just notice last line in my analysis titled "`Total`" (of number of times printf is executed). Those numbers definitely not seem to be O(n^4). For example, for i=3, total = 9 = O(i^2), while for i=4, Total = 24. Thus, O(i^2) < Total < O(i^3). Am I right?

Comment: Big O notation is used in the asymptotic analysis, meaning for very very large inputs. You just cannot analyze complexity using actual numbers. It is the wrong way.